# console.log shows object Object in an angular form

Tags: forms, angular, radio-button

Following and advice I'm trying to do a template driven form. But if I atempt to log in the console the userForm.value I just get " [object Object] " What am I doing wrong?

```
<form *ngIf="data" #userForm="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let item of data" (change)="Update(item.id, userForm.value)">
        <input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" value="1" required ngModel>Foo
        <input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" value="2" ngModel>Bar
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** ,

```
JSON.stringify(userForm.value);
```